# Android AlertDialog multiple choice mode issues

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have set my AlertDialog to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and get the data for the list from an API. It works almost fine, however, there are 2 problems I am having troubles with now.

1. The first one is more serious: After I check the items then click OK, sometimes when I go back to the dialog again it unchecks all of my checked items. This happens only 10-20% the times when I test so I do not know why it happens. I tried to save the values into a global variable in my class, or a public static variable I created when the app first started, still no luck.
2. When I click "Cancel", the checked items still update (it's supposed not to do so).

I am having a hard time against these 2 issues, any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my custom dialog:

```
public class CustomMultichoiceDialog {

    Set<String> selectedString = new HashSet<String>();

    private String[] items;

    private AlertDialog dialog;

    private Builder builder;

    private Context context;

    private TestAdapter adapter;

    public CustomMultichoiceDialog(Context context, String[] items) {

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        this.adapter = new TestAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, this.items);
        builder.setAdapter(this.adapter, null);

    }

    public AlertDialog show() {

        if (this.dialog == null) {
            this.create();
        }

        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        this.dialog.show();

        return this.dialog;
    }

    public String[] getSelectedItems() {
        String[] result = new String[this.dialog.getListView().getCheckedItemCount()];

        SparseBooleanArray checked = this.dialog.getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if (checked.get(i)) {
                result[k++] = this.items[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getSelectedItemAsString() {
        return Arrays.toString(this.getSelectedItems()).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
      .replace(", ", ",");
    }

    public AlertDialog create() {
        this.dialog = builder.create();
        this.dialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        this.dialog.getListView().setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        return this.dialog;
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(final Callbacks callbacks) {
        this.builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String[] selected = getSelectedItems();
                callbacks.run(selected, getSelectedItemAsString());
                cacheSelectedItems(selected);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setNegativeButton(final Callbacks callbacks) {
        this.builder.setNegativeButton(this.context.getString(R.string.cancel),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              }
        });
    }

    private void cacheSelectedItems(String[] selected) {
        selectedString.addAll(Arrays.asList(selected));
    }

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void run(String[] selectedItems, String selectedItemAsString);
    }

    class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public TestAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = ((CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
                holder.text.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
            }

            if(selectedString!=null){
                if(selectedString.contains(holder.text.getText().toString())) {
                holder.text.setSelected(true);
                holder.text.setChecked(true);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            CheckedTextView text;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: No one can help unless you post your code! Please and thank you.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I have updated my code. I get the data from API in another fragment, then pass into the constructor of this class via String[] items